# Bind a dynamically populated Array in Angular2 using *ngfor

Tags: angular

I'm trying to dynamically populate an array in Angular2. Below is my

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'pm-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {        
    ngOnInit(): void {
        let numbers: number[] = [];
        for (var i=1; i <= 9; i++) {
            numbers.push(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the HTML content:

```html
<div id="numbers-frame">
    <div class="well">
        <div *ngFor="let number of numbers; let i = index">
          {{i}} {{number}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm not getting any output at all. Can anyone please tell what am I doing wrong in this? Thanks.

Comment: numbers variable is  is local variable move it to the class level .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular2 looks at the component as context. You should declare `numbers` property within your component:

```
export class AppComponent {   
  numbers: number[] = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    for (var i=1; i <= 9; i++) {
      this.numbers.push(i);
    }
  }
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/w8DASJjfUJz0MKHnWQFc?p=preview)**

Comment: @Pankaj Parkar  Possible you're right. Anyway angular factory contains code `self.context.numbers` and it's `undefined` in his case